# Как правильно построить архитектуру API, если предполагается общение "сервер-сервер"?

Tags: php, laravel, api, архитектура

Всем привет. Разрабатываю приложение, но не понимаю, как решить данную задачу.

Есть приложение на Laravel, где описана вся клиентская часть: авторизация, оплата, валидация данных и т.д. На этом сервере клиенты вбивают свои данные, которые впоследствии отправляются на сервер-обработчик, где эти данные обрабатываются в порядке очереди, а затем отправляются обратно вместе с файлом, который был скомпилирован сервером.

Вид запроса на данный момент:

```
{
  project_id: 1,
  document_id: 10,
  client_id: 2,
  data: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Сервер-обработчик работает написан тоже на Laravel, использую "родные" очереди. На данный момент на этом сервере нет никакой аутентификации, т.е. если отправить запрос с любого места, то запрос обработается. Какие варианты вижу я:

- Использование "белого листа" IP адресов на уровне nginx
- Написание API и последующие передачи заголовка типа `Authorization: "Bearer xxx"`
- Использование "родного" Laravel Passort *(считаю избыточным)*

Как Вы считаете, стоит ли на данном этапе делать какое-либо API для работы с другими серверами? Если да, то каким образом делать? Использовать тот же JWT? Но тогда мне нужно создавать API-user'ов, у которых будет логин-пароль, а это отдельная система авторизации, что лишь нагрузит систему. Интересно услышать мнения людей, которые уже данные системы разрабатывали, буду рад любой критике.

Comment: Я так понимаю у вас API взаимодействие `сервер-сервер`. Белого листа думаю более чем достаточно, хотя все равно используют токены которые содержат и ключ для декодирования данных. Обычно в чистом виде инфу не передают даже и на таком уровне (если не локальное взаимодействие).

Comment: В одном из проектов было подобное решение — laravel подняли на специфичном порту + добавили проверку по ip адресу. Шифрования данных не использовали, хотя соглашусь с предыдущим комментарием, что так будет надежнее. Мы только сжимали сообщения gzip'ом.